# iPython Notebook keyboard shortcut to continue editing code

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I execute a cell in iPython by pressing command+enter, it moves to the next cell. Frequently I'd like to quickly go back to the previous cell and modify the code snippet, and would prefer not reaching for my mouse.

The up arrow brings me back to the cell I just executed.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to continue typing in that cell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift-enter` execute cell and select the next, `ctrl-enter` execute and keep the same cell selected. Please read the help -> keyboard shortcut dialog.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL-Enter`, `Enter`

(Release `CTRL` before the second `Enter`.)

`CTRL-Enter` 1) executes the cell, 2) keeps you in the same cell, and 3) puts you into command mode.

`Enter` puts you into input/editing mode again.